# Looking for an algorithm f(min,max,[v0.0 ... v1.0]) = value between min and max.....

Tags: algorithms

I am writing a program where I need to have a circle animation that grows from a start value to a end value and back to the starting value.

I was able to come up with a semi-solution while googling.

```
double radiusFromProgress(double progress, double maxValue) {
  // Ensure progress is in the range [0, 1]
  progress = progress.clamp(0.0, 1.0);

  // Map progress to the range [0, pi]
  double angle = progress * pi;

  // Use the sine function to create the desired oscillation
  double output = maxValue * sin(angle);

  // Ensure output is non-negative
  output = max(0.0, output);

  return output;
}
```

But this function does not take into account the minimal value, so I need to update it to take a minValue in to account.

the form would be f(min,max,progress)
the progress values are clamped between 0.0 and 1.0.
at 0.5 the output is max and for 0.0 and 1.0 is min.
example:

```
a = 10
b = 50
f(a, b, 0.0) =  10
f(a, b, 0.5) =  50
f(a, b, 1.0) =  10
```

Edit: If you are to give me a -1 at least be constructive and leave a comment saying why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly I think this should work for the function $f$ you seek.

Linearly interpolate between $a$ and $b$ for $t$ from $0$ to $1/2$, then from $b$ to $a$ for  $t$ from $1/2$ to $1$.

$$
f(a,b,t) =
\begin{cases}
(1-2t)a + 2tb & 0 \le t \le 1/2 \\
?? & 1/2 \le t \le 1.
\end{cases}
$$

You should be able to finish the linear interpolation.

Note: The code does not seem to refer to the function you seek. I have not read it (nor should we be asked to on this site).

Comment: The code as I mention does not give the result I was seeking to get as I was not able to use pi and get values in the range I wanted them to be, it does work if min value is 0. Sorry about the code, I dit not find out how to write a math formula using the markdown from the site. and not having done any maths in 30 years my trigonometry is mostly forgotten and I was certain that using PI was the way to go. So if I get this right if c is below 0.5 {a + 2 * c * (b - a)}  otherwise {b - 2 * (c - 0.5) * (b - a)}. tested it in dart pad and it works. thanks